# UART - wiringSerial.h vs standard Linux open/close

Tags: linux, serial, uart, c

I'm making an application that uses the UART port from the 40pin headers and I found online that there's a library called `wiringSerial.h`

I was wondering what's the difference between `wiringSerial.h` and the standard `open` `close` `unistd.h` method we use on Linux machines?

My Raspberry Pi runs raspbian lite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wiringSerial is part of wiringPi.

wiringPi is an "Arduino" like C library to control the GPIO.

wiringSerial is a simple wrapper around the underlying Linux serial driver.  It simplifies some operations.  Look at the source code if you need details.

Note that wiringPi is deprecated (i.e. no longer being developed or supported by its author).

Comment: I noticed that it looks abandoned. Thanks

Comment: There are at least two other C libraries.  My pigpio and the bcm2835 library.  pigpio does offer a wrapper around serial operations.